# Multiply Array Elements by Index Position

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to take the elements of an array, multiply them by their index position, and add the results together.

So if I had:

```
array = [1, 2, 3]
```

I would get 8.

```
// (1 * 0)+(2 * 1)+(3 * 2) = 8
```

What is the best way to do this in vanilla JS, simply for learning purposes?

Comment: For learning purposes, you should probably try doing it yourself. Start with a for-loop.

Comment: `var t = 0, i = array.length; while(i--) t+= i * array[i];`

Comment: `[1, 2, 3].reduce((s, n, i) => s + (n * i), 0);`

Comment: Thanks you so much guys! My post for someone didn't include the part where I was frustrated over this for hours... but this morning I figured it out, using two for-loops, in the most convoluted was possible. But it works. So thank you for showing me the *best* way to do it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A functional, semantic approach would be:

```
const add      = (a, b) => a + b;
const multiply = (a, b) => a * b;
```

To sum an array:

```
const sum      = a => a.reduce(add, 0);
```

To add up the products of value and index as you want:

```
const weightedSum = a => sum(a.map(multiply));
```

We're able to say `a.map(multiply)` because `map` happens to pass the value and the index to the callback `multiply`.

Of course, this might be more than you want or need to learn at this point. There's nothing wrong with an old-fashioned for loop, as others have mentioned:

```
function weightedSum(a) {
  sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) sum += a[i] * i;
  return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A very simple way would be:

```js
console.log(
                 // ┌ the running total
                 // │  ┌ the current array value
                 // │  │  ┌ the current array index
                 // │  │  │
  [1, 2, 3].reduce((s, n, i) => s + (n * i), 0)
);
```

Manual: [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Answer (score 1):

```
var array = [1, 2, 3];
var items = array.map(function(x,i){
    return x * i;
});
var sum = items.reduce(function(init, x) {
    return x + init,0
});// 8
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a map to multiply by index and then use a reduce to obtain the sum

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3]
var result = array.map((x,i) => x*i).reduce((a,b) => a+b,0);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

several approaches, but simplest for you to understand would be:

```
var numbers = [1,2,3]; 
var sum = 0; 
for(var i = 0;i < numbers.length; i++){
    sum+= (i*numbers[i]);
}
console.log(sum);
```

Comment: note: also, maybe should pass numbers.length into variable, due to better performances, but this is just example

Comment: Caching length in for loops leading to better performance is an old wives' tale--the engine will optimize this for you.

Comment: yes, but it is recommendation, so to get used to cache some outputs from methods that have heavy code within :). 
I saw very often methods within "for" loops that have a lot of processes within, which is craaazy :))

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = 0;
for(i=0;i<array.length;i++)
{
    var val = array[i];
    result += val*i;
}
alert(result);
```

Comment: There's nothing particularly wrong with this solution, but don't you want to declare `i`, and what is the purpose of storing the value in `val`?